# Connection Failed Error with PicKit3 and MPlabX (IDE and IPE)

Tags: c, ubuntu, pic, microchip, mplab

I'm trying to programm my PIC 16F628A with PICKIT3 in MPlabX, but I get the following error:

> ***************************************************** Connection Failed.

When I enable the "Power Target Circuit From Tool", I get another error:

> The target circuit may require more power than the debug tool can provide. An external power supply might be necessary.
>   Connection Failed.

So a provided an external power supply of 5V and my PIC 16F628A is draining 10mA, despite nothing is connected, only the PICKIT3 to the MCLR, ICSPDATA and ICSPCLK pins of PIC.

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04, MPlabX IPE V4.05., and

PS: Yes, I know how to read a datasheet.

PS: Circuit and PICKIT3 works properlyt if I connect to PICKIT3 Programmer running on Windows 7.

Answer (score 2):

The first issue can sometimes be resolved by shutting down MPLABX, disconnecting the PicKit from your computer and reconnecting everything. Seems the firmware and/or driver sometimes gets in a weird state and needs a good boot to get going again. I sometimes have to reboot my computer just to program my main board (Major PITA).

The second issue is not necessarily caused by an over current despite the message. I always got this error when my PicKit was plugged into an unpowered USB hub. It seems the lower USB bus voltage confuses the PicKit into thinking that the device is the cause for the voltage drop instead of the host simply not supplying the normal voltage. Try plugging it into a powered USB hub or directly into your computer.

Comment: I also get the error: "The target circuit may require more power than the debug tool can provide. An external power supply might be necessary.
Connection Failed." Althought i´ve powered the target with 5V.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old topic but maybe this answer can help somebody else.

I use as well official PICKIT's as clones.

It could indeed be caused by a hardware issue.
E.g. short or already activated load like a  bunch of LED's.
Disconnect all loads if possible.

When using an **official PICKIT 3**, this issue is often solved by setting the voltage your PICKIT should supply to a lower level e.g. 5 => 4.625.
In MPLAB go to the properties of your project.
Select PICKIT on the left.
Select Power from the selection dropdown at the top.

When you have a SURE electronics **clone**, this might do the trick. (Maybe this is also valid for other clones) The AMS1117 they used is the adjustable one.
They used a 680 and a 470 feedback resistor which gives a voltage of 3.09V ((680/470 +1))*1.25 + 50u * 680). If you swap the 680 Ohm resistor with a 750, the output will be closer to the probably desired 3.3V.
Source where I got the idea: https://jrainimo.com/build/2018/12/picfix/

[Location FB resistor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gS9Qo.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Close MPlab, reconnect Pickkit, restart MPlab worked for me.
If you've just created a new project or created a new file, MPlab sometimes confuses some things.